# WCF Castle Windsor and WAS

Tags: .net, wcf, castle-windsor

I have a service that is hosted in WAS. I am trying to inject this service with dependencies, but have been having trouble finding where to do this. In a WCF service hosted in IIS you can use the application_onstart event to instantiate the castle container, but this isn't available in my scenario. So, I am trying to create a custom host factory like so:

```
public override ServiceHostBase CreateServiceHost(string constructorString, Uri[] baseAddresses)
        {
            container = new WindsorContainer();
            container.Register(Component.For<IMyDependency>().ImplementedBy<MyDependency>());
            DefaultServiceHostFactory.RegisterContainer(container.Kernel);

            var service = container.Resolve(constructorString);
            ServiceHost serviceHost = new ServiceHost(service, baseAddresses);

            return serviceHost;
        }
```

This works fine with singleton WCF services, but how do you get this to work with per-call? With non singleton services it is expecting a type to be passed to the ServiceHost constructor rather than an actual service. However, if I do this then when the service spins up it looks for a parameterless constructor only, not the DI version.

Any ideas on how to get this all working?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[WCF Facility](http://www.castleproject.org/container/facilities/trunk/wcf/index.html) will do that (and a lot more) for you.

Comment: Thanks, I have got WCF Facility working with WCF services activated in IIS before, but not WAS. In the past I simply hooked the service up to the Wcf factory then added the container in the global.asax. However, I cannot hook up the container in global.asax with WAS, so how would you put this all together?

Comment: The answer is to hook into AppInitialize()

Thanks

Comment: cool, glad you made it work. If you have any questions regarding Castle, it's best to ask on the discussion list: http://groups.google.com/group/castle-project-users